# Super method returning undefined for defined variable in Es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My super method returns undefined for the age variable, I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
class customer_info{

    constructor(name, age = 50, gender){
        this.name = 'Lambo';
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = 'Male';
    }

    getCustomerInfo(){
      let customer_list = {Names: this.name, Age: this.age, Gender: this.gender};
      return customer_list;
    }

}

let cust = new customer_info('Micheal Lambo', 49, "male");

class account_details extends customer_info {

    constructor(account_no, account_name, initial_deposit){
        super(name, age);
        this.account_no = account_no;
        this.account_name = account_name;
        this.initial_deposit = initial_deposit;
    }

    deposit(){

    }

    withdrawal(){

    }

    balance(){

    }

    getCustomerAccount(){
      return super.getCustomerInfo();
    }

}

let cust_acct = new account_details();
cust_acct.getCustomerAccount();
```

Comment: When you do `super(name, age);`, where are you expecting the `name` and `age` values to come from that you pass to `super()`?  As your code shows here, that would cause an error because neither `name` or `age` are defined variables in the code you show.  Though I don't think it would make a lot of sense, your code would probably work if you just did `super()` instead because in the constructor, you aren't using the first or third argument and the second has a default value.

Comment: But, it is probably wrong code to be defining `constructor(name, age = 50, gender)` and then not use the `name` or `gender` arguments at all.  That will confuse the heck out of anyone using the `customer_info` object because they will pass in a `name` and `gender` arguments, but your implementation will hard wire the `name` to `Lambo` and the `gender` to `Male`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

In this constructor

```
class account_details extends customer_info{
    constructor(account_no, account_name, initial_deposit){
        super(name, age);
        this.account_no = account_no;
        this.account_name = account_name;
        this.initial_deposit = initial_deposit;
    }
```

name and age are not defined, pass them as parameters to the constructor.

```
class account_details extends customer_info{
    constructor(name, age, account_no, account_name, initial_deposit){
        super(name, age);
        this.account_no = account_no;
        this.account_name = account_name;
        this.initial_deposit = initial_deposit;
    }
```

And then call it like this:

```
let cust_acct = new account_details('name', 32, account_no, account_name, initial_deposit);
```